# Google Cloud Functions - Cloud SQL Aborted Connection

Tags: python, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-sql

Using cloud functions to pull data from an external source and save in a Cloud SQL database, I regularly see these messages:

`{TIMESTAMP} 18063 [Note] Aborted connection 18063 to db: '{DB_NAME}' user: '{DB_USER}' host: '{DB_HOST}' (Got an error reading communication packets)`

Based on my research so far, this does not have a measurable impact on the performance of the function, but I like clean logs and would like to solve this. It has something to do with not properly closing connections, BUT, see the below code, I am not sure what else I should be doing here.

```
class DatabaseConnection:
    def __init__(self):
        db_config = {
            "pool_size": 5,
            "max_overflow": 2,
            "pool_timeout": 30,
            "pool_recycle": 1800
        }
        self.engine = sqla.create_engine(f"mysql+pymysql://{DB_USER}:{DB_PASS}@{DB_HOST}:{DB_PORT}/{DB_NAME}", **db_config)
        self.conn = sessionmaker(bind=self.engine)
        Base.metadata.create_all(self.engine, checkfirst=True)
        self.meta = MetaData()

    def query_database(self):
        session = self.conn()
        items = session.query(DB_ITEM).all()
        session.close()
        return items

db = DatabaseConnection()
items = db.query_database()
```

Comment: How to do you reach the database? With the Cloud SQL connection on Cloud Functions or through the private IP (and you use a serverless VPC connector)?

Comment: As you can see on this [MySQL documentation](https://www.percona.com/blog/2016/05/16/mysql-got-an-error-reading-communication-packet-errors/), a possible cause for this issue might be that you have exceeded the max_allowed_packet for queries, is this a possibility in your app?

Comment: Answering the two above questions: database reached via Cloud SQL connection on the Cloud Function (the code is from the function itself) because setting up a Proxy is a lot of work for what is a pretty simple function. Second, max_allowed_packet is highly unlikely since the data is very small (usually adding a single row with a couple features and no text longer than 300 characters)